# Outlook web / PWA - how to find what folder an email is in

Tags: microsoft-outlook, outlook-web-access

I am using Microsoft Outlook PWA, I believe this is the same as Outlook on the web.
I have searched all over to try and find a solution for this but to no avail.

There are certain scenarios when it's helpful to know where an email is stored/located.
When searching and you find an email, you want to know is it in the right location or should I move it?
Sometimes you do something to an email and it seems to disappear from the inbox, it would be useful to know where it's gone to and not just move it again.

So, I cannot find a single way to find out what folder an email is in.
I've tried adding folder columns, viewing the folders in the left hand side menu for a highlighted folder, doing the same in the 'move to' dropdown, opening email properties, etc.
There is no easy way to find an emails folder location and there does not seem to be any way.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're looking at, but I use Outlook PWA in Chrome and in the search results, it tells me which folder the email is in:

[image: outlook pwa screenshot]

I don't think I've modified my PWA settings in any significant way.

Answer (score 0):

It is a shame that if you are using OWA or such similar thing, you could not find the email folder location.

The email on OWA would not save in local folder， it is located in cloud by default.
Unless you use Outlook Client, you cannot save the mails as .PST file in Local folder.

You can try to install Outlook Client then you can find and save the email in local folder.

About how to backup your mails as .pst file ,you can info this Microsoft Blog:[enter link description here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/export-or-backup-email-contacts-and-calendar-to-an-outlook-pst-file-14252b52-3075-4e9b-be4e-ff9ef1068f91)